# Padding out a string so that substring functions don't fail

Tags: .net, string, padding

There is some code I've adopted and it's failing because it's doing a substring to extract specific parts of the string:

```
policyMemo.Line1 = policyAllMemoText[i].Substring(17)
```

The problem comes into play when the string length is shorter than 17.

I could easily just check the length and handle it that way, however in this method, `policyAllMemoText[i]` has many different substrings applied to get information from.

The highest I see is `policyAllMemoText[i].Substring(30)`

Does it make sense to pad the string to the highest possible length 30?  I'm thinking not because this is a service layer and if someone is displaying `policyAllMemeText` somewhere - they could start seeing a bunch of spaces (due to any padding) and that could cause formatting issues for them.  I guess I could always Trim the extra spaces before exiting the method?

Comment: Could you please add an example to illustrate your problem. The question seems not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to get all the string from your index on to the end just use LINQ `Skip()` method.

`String.Join( "", policyAllMemoText[i].Skip(17) )`

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion there are 2 ways:

1st:
You check the length before you try to substring. (Like you described it already)

2nd:
You use "try" to do it and if it fails the program goes to "catch"

I recommend the 1st one.

Comment: Actually I did the try/catch.  In fact, being a service layer, I thought it would be a good idea to return an exception indicating there is incomplete data on the memo, but I lost that battle.  :)